# How could we establish connection between server and client through socket programming(Python) with server and client on different networks?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

How could we establish connection between server and client through socket programming(Python) with server and client on different devices and on different networks? When we create socket with i/p addr and port
of server, server and client gets connected if both devices are connected on same network. But this is not the case with different networks. What needs to be done to connect them?

```py
import socket
def server_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000 
    server_socket = socket.socket()  
    server_socket.bind((host, port)) 
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            break
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))
        data = input(' -> ')
        conn.send(data.encode())  
    conn.close()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

```py
import socket
def client_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()   // used ngrok i/p here
    port = 5000                   // used ngrok port no
    client_socket = socket.socket()  
    client_socket.connect((host, port))
    message = input(" -> ") 

    while message.lower().strip() != 'bye':
        client_socket.send(message.encode()) 
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode() 

        print('Received from server: ' + data)

        message = input(" -> ") 
    client_socket.close() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

Comment: *"But this is not the case with different networks."* - __Different networks are not a problem__, i.e. one could easily have an internal client and some external server on the internet. That's how normal communication between browser and web server and similar works. And the same can be done with Python. The problem is only if systems inside the networks can reach each other or if there are firewalls or routing which limit connectivity. __Workarounds around connectivity problems depend on the specific problem__ but might involve firewall settings, port forwarding or using external helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To establish a connection between server and client on different networks you either need to use [port forwarding](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-port-forward-4163829#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Forward%20Ports%20on%20Your%20Router%201,out%20if%20a%20firewall%20program%20blocked%20the%20) or you can take help of some external software like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

> How do you use ngrok ?

1. First of all you need to sign up.
2. Download the ngrok software
3. Now you would get a screen like this

[image]

4. Copy the line `./ ngrok authtoken .........`
5. Open up cmd and cd into the folder where you've downloaded ngrok
6. Paste the copied commmand (**Note**- If you're on windows remove the  `./` from starting of the command) and hit enter
7. Enter the following command

```
ngrok tcp [Port on which your server is listening]
```

For example - If your server is listening on port 65432 then you'd have to enter the following command

```
ngrok tcp 65432
```

You should now be seeing a window like this

[image]

8. Copy the `x.tcp.ngrok......` from the window (highlited in the image above)
9. Open up cmd and type `ping [copied text here]`
   The output should be something like this :

```
Pinging x.tcp.ngrok...... [ip here] with 32 bytes of data:
....
....
....
```

10. Copy the ip
11. Now in your `client.py` file replace the ip with the ip you copied
12. Copy the port from the ngrok window (Next to the highlighted text in the image above, in my case it's 11171)
13. Replace the port in `client.py` file with the port you copied
14. In `server.py` change the host to `"0.0.0.0"`
15. You're all set to go now! Clients can now connect to your server from all over the globe

Comment: When I type "ping x.tcp....." I am getting 100% packet loss. So when I finally used that I/P and port no in client.py, in ngrok windows I can see connection = 1 when server and client are connected but data/msg is not being sent to each other between server/client

Comment: Could you pls add `client.py` and `server.py` code in your question?

Comment: btw, 100% packets loss is the expected scenario

Comment: I have added client.py and server.py.

Comment: Ah my bad, You also need to change the host to `"0.0.0.0"` in `server.py`